# How to switch views like instagram profile ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, dynamic, view, containers

How can I switch views like Instagram profile which user can tap a button and it switch to different views.I suspect Instagram is using container views but I don't know for sure, should I stack view above another view and hide another view ? If it is using container views how can I make the container view dynamic height base on the view inside the container ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make that using tabbar. 
Check out tabbar tutorials online they will guide you how you can get what you want.

Comment: Aren't tab bar are supposed to be on the bottom ?